# How to show an incoming call when screen is locked on react-native

Tags: android, webrtc, react-native

I'm developing a video call app with react-native-webrtc and I'm stuck now on how to show the incoming call screen when the phone is locked. I'm working now on the android part and I already tried this tutorial but it doesn't work for me https://medium.com/@shivanshrajpoot/create-a-react-native-app-which-works-on-lock-screen-android-b127f0177455

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

React Native CallKeep is what you need.
You can find the usage details here..
https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep

Comment: I also saw an article about this react-native-call, but it's hard to set it up, do you have any demo resources?

https://blog.theodo.com/2021/03/react-native-incoming-call-ui-callkeep/

Answer (score 0):

To display an incoming call screen when the screen is locked in a React Native app, you can use the react-native-incoming-call package. Here's a simple example:

1. Install the package using npm or yarn:

   npm install react-native-incoming-call

or

```
yarn add react-native-incoming-call
```

2. Import the package in your React Native code:

   import IncomingCall from 'react-native-incoming-call';
3. Show the incoming call screen when you receive an incoming call event:

   IncomingCall.show({
   callTitle: 'Incoming Call',
   contactName: 'John Doe',
   avatar: 'https://picsum.photos/100',
   onDecline: () => {},
   onAccept: () => {}
   });

Here, callTitle and contactName are the title and name of the incoming call, respectively, while avatar is an optional profile picture. onDecline and onAccept are the callbacks that will be called when the user declines or accepts the call, respectively.

This should give you an idea of how to show an incoming call screen when the screen is locked in React Native. You can further customize this code to meet your specific needs.